# Python/Django on IIS with Windows Authentication - "The connection sessions doesn't exist"

Tags: python, django, iis

I am running a Python/Django API on Windows IIS and have windows authentication active. The actual authentication part is working fine. However whenever I try and visit any web page or endpoint on the server, I get this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: ** My URL **

Django Version: 1.9.4
Python Version: 3.4.4
Installed Applications:
[
 '** Custom Apps **',
 'rest_framework',
 'corsheaders',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in ensure_defaults
  177.             conn = self.databases[alias]

During handling of the above exception ('sessions'), another exception occurred:

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  123.                 response = middleware_method(request)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\middleware.py" in process_request
  94.             auth.login(request, user)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in login
  110.         request.session.cycle_key()

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py" in cycle_key
  302.         self.create()

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py" in create
  49.             self._session_key = self._get_new_session_key()

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py" in _get_new_session_key
  155.             if not self.exists(session_key):

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py" in exists
  45.         return self.model.objects.filter(session_key=session_key).exists()

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in exists
  651.             return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in has_results
  500.         compiler = q.get_compiler(using=using)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in get_compiler
  254.             connection = connections[using]

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __getitem__
  209.         self.ensure_defaults(alias)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in ensure_defaults
  179.             raise ConnectionDoesNotExist("The connection %s doesn't exist" % alias)

Exception Type: ConnectionDoesNotExist at /api/v1/test/
Exception Value: The connection sessions doesn't exist
```

I am still kind of new to Django so I am not 100% sure what the `sessions` is or why it is failing. I should also note that on my development server, which is a simple `manage.py runserver` in a python console instead of IIS, this issue does not occurr.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It cannot find a database or the supplied database setting are incorrect

Comment: It's strange then, it could find the database before I turned on windows authentication. Will have to root around for this.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually an issue with using routing over multiple databases. In my development server no authentication is taking place - so the database is not interacted with.

What I found was that Django was trying to communicate with the 'auth' and 'sessions' database alias'. I was not handling these names properly in my router.py, so they were not being allowed to read and write data.